# OOP Design Patterns using C++

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns

Good day all

Where can one fine good introductory material on design patterns in OOP using C++ ?

Specifically for the the following patterns:

- Composite pattern
- Observer pattern
- Flyweight pattern
- Serializer pattern
- Monostate pattern
- Command pattern

Any info, links to sites or books will be most appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the best design patterns books you have read?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105049/what-are-the-best-design-patterns-books-you-have-read)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5748983/gang-of-four-design-patterns-are-those-pattern-samples-coded-in-outdated-way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess there are many books and sources where you can find this information around, I'll point to you a couple of books that you can find in both paper and PDF formats around the net:

1. "Design Patterns, by the “Gang of Four” (Addison-Wesley,1994). The definitive guide to patterns. It  has examples in both C++ and Smalltalk, although it can be a bit diffuclt to follow.
2. "Design Patterns for dummies", by Steve Holdner (Willey Publisinh Inc., 2006) This book is a lot simpler and easier to understunf/follow. From a Computer Science point of view it might be a bit "weak" or informal, but I'm sure that you can start by understunding a given design pattern through this book and get a more detailed/formal information with the GoF publication.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5748983/gang-of-four-design-patterns-are-those-pattern-samples-coded-in-outdated-way

Comment: Thanks Ignacio the Design Patterns for dummies looks especially promising as introductory material.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.vincehuston.org/dp/